# Angular cli doesn't seem to download correctly

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

`I want to see the ng version inside an folder of an angular project (which contains an Angular.json-file and package.json-file).
Every package seems to be downloaded correctly, but Angular itself seems to create an error.
-->"Angular: <error>"

```
Angular CLI: 15.1.1
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 9.2.0
OS: win32 x64

\*\*Angular: \<error\>   \*\*  
... animations, common, core, forms, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
-

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1501.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.1.1
@angular-devkit/core            15.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.1.1 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    15.1.1 (cli-only)
@angular/compiler               15.1.0
@angular/compiler-cli           15.1.0
@schematics/angular             15.1.1 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.9.4
```

I deleted and redownloaded Angular Cli but the problem doesn't change

When i type "ng version" in the command line it shows "Angular: undefined".

Does somebody have a idea what could be the problem?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have everything but angular/core package

so

try to run this

**npm i @angular/core**

Please let me know if anything change

Comment: Yes, sir, i ran it in the project folder and it worked:)   Im pretty new to angular so thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solution: i ran in the project folder

```
npm i @angular/core
```

and it worked.